# Mapping DTO to specific subclass of parent entiy using Spring JPA where InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to map DTO to the corresponding `@Entity` in the service layer.
`Condition` may be of a set of types: `Amount`, `Title`, `Date`. Each condition, except `Amount`, has a unique predefined set of clauses.

- **TitleCondition:** `includes`, `startsWith`
- **DateCondition:** `from`, `until`

The idea is to use common `Condition` entity with `@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.

The 2 problems I see with this code is:

1. It is unclear how to properly set `data`
2. data type is `Object`

Is there a way to use convenient Lombok's `@Builder` with given mapping? What would be the simpler and better way to map dto to entity?

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class FilterService {

    private Condition convertConditionDtoToEntity(ConditionDto conditionDto) {
        Type type = typeRepository.findFirstByName(conditionDto.getType())
                .orElseThrow(UnsupportedOperationException::new);

        Clause clause;
        if (conditionDto.getClause() != null) {
            clause = clauseRepository.findFirstByName().orElseThrow(UnsupportedOperationException::new);
        }
        
        if (conditionDto.getType().equals("amount")) {
            return AmountCondition.builder().type(type).data(???).build();
        } else if (conditionDto.getType().equals("title")) {
            return TitleCondition.builder().type(type).clause(clause).data(???).build();
        } else if (conditionDto.getType().equals("date")) {
            return DateCondition.builder().type(type).clause(clause).data(???).build();
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Condition**

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Condition {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Filter filter;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne
    public Type type;

    public abstract Object getData();
}
```

**DateCondition**

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class DateCondition extends Condition {
    @Column
    int clauseId;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date date;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne
    private Clause clause;

    @Override
    public Object getData() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

**TitleCondition**

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class TitleCondition extends Condition {
    @Column
    int clauseId;

    @Column
    String title;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne
    private Clause clause;

    @Override
    public Object getData() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

**AmountCondition**

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class AmountCondition extends Condition {
    @Column
    int amount;

    @Override
    public Object getData() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

**Clause**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Clause {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clause")
    private Set<Type> types = new HashSet();
}
```

**Type**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Clause clause;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private Set<Condition> conditions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two forms that I use a lot and save a lot of time.
first: transform your model into json and convert the json to object the Mapper class (this link will help https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

second: spring has some cool functions about it. an example would be the BeanUtils.copyProperties function (source, target);

data problem: the data field does not exist for this reason you do not need to set it.

Another problem that I was able to notice is that their properties are all defaulted so set them as private.